# Get Transaction Additional Info in magento refund

Tags: payment-gateway, refund, transaction, additional-information

I am making a custom payment gateway and I have it in the `capture payment` in Magento when a payment has been through:

```
$payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo                     
           (Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,array
('TransactionGUId'=>$result['transaction_guid'], 'TransactionId'=>$result
['transaction_id'],'Messages'=>$result['messages']));
```

Which writes the payment transaction additional information.
I need to get in the refund these additional informations to send them to the payment Gateway.
I tried:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $payment->getOrder()->getEntityId()))
 ->addAttributeToFilter('txn_type', array('eq' => 'capture'))
        ->addPaymentIdFilter($payment->getId());


       $transaction = $collection->getAdditionalInformation('transactionId');
        $transactionGUId = $collection->getAdditionalInformation('transactionGUId');
```

but it returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the individual object from the collection

Try

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id',  
                      array('eq' => $payment->getOrder()->getEntityId()))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('txn_type', array('eq' => 'capture'))
                  ->addPaymentIdFilter($payment->getId());


 foreach($collection as $transaction){
       print_r($transaction->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS));
 }
```

Update - your key is Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS

In order to get the individual value try

```
$rawValue = $transaction->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAIL)
if(is_array($rawValue) && array_key_exist(...)){
    $transactionGUId = $rawValue['TransactionGUId']; 
    ...
}
```

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Transaction.php,

```
 /**
 * Additional information setter
 * Updates data inside the 'additional_information' array
 * Doesn't allow to set arrays
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function setAdditionalInformation($key, $value)
{
    if (is_object($value)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment transactions disallow storing objects.'));
    }
    $info = $this->_getData('additional_information');
    if (!$info) {
        $info = array();
    }
    $info[$key] = $value;
    return $this->setData('additional_information', $info);
}

/**
 * Getter for entire additional_information value or one of its element by key
 * @param string $key
 * @return array|null|mixed
 */
public function getAdditionalInformation($key = null)
{
    $info = $this->_getData('additional_information');
    if (!$info) {
        $info = array();
    }
    if ($key) {
        return (isset($info[$key]) ? $info[$key] : null);
    }
    return $info;
}
```

Comment: but i need to get separately two data when i write foreach i don't get them separately how can i get $transactionID = ...and $transactionGUID =... these are two keys with values in the transaction additional information i need to get these two values to send them in a xml file

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($transaction->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS);`

Comment: I don't know how can i find out i have  a problem i only see the answer of the request i can't see the request itself my code is as follows:

Comment: Take a look at my update... try Mage::log($transaction->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_T‌​ransaction::RAW_DETAILS))

Comment: great thank you! the following worked foreach($collection as $transaction){
$rawValue = $transaction->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS);
if(is_array($rawValue)){
    $transactionGuid = $rawValue['TransactionGUId']; 
    
}
}